# PHP: imagick add space in between appended images?

Tags: php, imagick

I'm using imagick to append some images to a background image. this works fine... but the the appended images are sticking together..

is there anyway to put a space between them at all?

This is my code:

```
exec("/usr/bin/convert H.png E.png L.png L.png O.png +append append_row.gif");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would just pad the original images being appended or create a "space.png" and add that between the images.

Comment: or in the docs it says there is a `gravity` setting. https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append

Comment: gravity is for centering the images! isn't it?